# How to schedule a query (Export Data) from Google Big Query to External Storage space (Eg: Box)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, job-scheduling

I read many articles and solutions regarding scheduling queries to external storage places in Google Big Query but they didn't seem to be that clear.

Note: My company has subscription only to Google Big Query and not to the complete cloud Services (Google Cloud Platform).

I know how to do it manually but I am looking to automate the process since I need the same data every week.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can use [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) which provides the option to create schedule task on to of BigQuery using BigQuery operator.

[image]

You can find in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-aggregate-data-for-bigquery-using-apache-airflow) the basic steps required to start setting this up

**option 2**

You can use the Google BigQuery [command line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) to export your data as you do from the webUI, for example:

```
bq --location=[LOCATION] extract --destination_format [FORMAT] --compression [COMPRESSION_TYPE] --field_delimiter [DELIMITER] --print_header [BOOLEAN] [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] gs://[BUCKET]/[FILENAME]
```

Once you get this working you can use any schedule process of your liking to schedule the run of this job

BTW: Airflow has a connector which enables you to run the command line tool

Once the file in GCP you can use Box [G suite integration](https://community.box.com/t5/Box-for-G-Suite-User-Guide/Upgrading-your-Box-for-G-Suite-Integration/ta-p/63325) to see and manage your files

[image]

Comment: how about ".. External Storage space (Eg: Box) ..."? :o)

Comment: Box is a cloud computing business which provides file-sharing, collaborating, and other tools for working with files that are uploaded to its servers. Users can determine how their content can be shared with other users. ... Box offers three account types: Enterprise, Business and Personal.

Comment: I was not asking what The Box is :o) my comment was about - does that answer address "External Storage space" aspect of your question. Does it? I was just curious about it

Comment: @Mikhail, I updated my answer to reflect your question

Comment: I thought the key question was "how to automate the process" including "External Storage". Sorry for being picky here - I am just interested in this topic

Comment: Sure. I added the extra step. Hope my answer is acceptable and worth voting up :)

Comment: @Siddhant Naik note: important on SO - you can mark accepted answer by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. See [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) for why it is important